# Nodejs EJS "Is not Defined" err

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am sending an array to an ejs template using Nodejs. Looks like we cannot pass an array to ejs so I am receiving the value like:

```
console.log(<%= val %>)
```

Rec - 159,Rec - 160

I tried to convert the above value to an array

> val= (<%= String(val) %>).split(",")

I get Rec is not defined and in the sources tab in my google console the line points to:

```
(Rec - 159,Rec - 160).split(",")
```

I want to change the value to an array so that I can loop through it and make some DOM changes but I cannot change it to an array for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did

```
val = orderNumber = <%- JSON.stringify(val) %>
```

And it converted it to an array